# get site path using a group id

Tags: javascript, groups

I have a list of groups a user is member of including the groups' name and id.
Now I need to construct URLs to the sites those groups are used in. (I can assume there is 1:1 relationship between group id and site).
I know I can iterate through all sub sites and their groups and compare, however this is quite expensive.
Any idea how to do this in a more elegant way?
Note: I want to achieve this via Javascript.